# Calling a variables function on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to trigger an items effect in an adventure game I am building and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Basically when clicked I would like whichever item it is to run their effect function. I'm getting quite confused.

```
    function showItems() {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        playerUi.innerHTML += '<div class="item-container"><a href="#" 
    class="item-name" onclick="items[i].effect">' + items[i].name + '</a><br 
    /><p class="desc-p">' + items[i].description + '<br />Value: ' + 
    items[i].price + '</p></div>';
      }
    }

    // Shows the inventory interface.
    $('#inv-btn').on('click', function() {
      playerUi.innerHTML = '<h3>Your Inventory:</h3>';
      showItems();
      playerUi.innerHTML += '<br /><br /><div class="gold-box">Gold: ' + 
    player.gold + '</div>';
    });
```

The below is the code I have for my items at the minute:

```
    // I  T  E  M  S
    function invItem(name, type, desc, price, eff) {
      this.name = name;
      this.type = type;
      this.description = desc;
      this.price = price;
      this.effect = eff;
    };

    var weakPotion = new invItem('Weak Potion', 'Consumable', 'A weak health 
    potion.', 10, healSelf(20));
    var brewersPotion = new invItem('Brewers Potion', 'Consumable', 'A 
    standard health potion.', 23, healSelf(45));

    function healSelf(amt) {
      if (player.currentHealth < player.maxHealth) {
        player.currentHealth += amt;
        if (player.currentHealth >= player.maxHealth) {
          player.currentHealth = player.maxHealth;
        }
      }
    }
```

To see what I currently have so far on this [click here](http://textadventure.whitespacehost.com/ta).

Below is my player object.

```
    // Create our player object.
    var player = new Object();
    player.gold = 0;
    player.level = 1;
    player.strength = 5;
    player.intellect = 5;
    player.endurance = 5;
    player.agility = 5;
    player.currentExp = 0;
    player.reqExp = 100;
    player.skillPoints = 0;
    player.attPoints = 2;
    player.maxHealth = 0;
    player.currentHealth = 0;
    player.maxMana = 0;
    player.currentMana = 0;
```

Comment: What's confusing? what's happening and what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a link at the bottom of my question that shows what I have so far with my game. So when the name of the item is clicked I would like it to trigger the function contained within the items .function variable. So for example when clicked on the Weak Potion name, I would like the players current health to increase by 20. Use the test button to add EXP and then assign attribute points to Endurance to see a less than full HP bar.

Comment: Where does `player` come from in your `healSelf` function?

Comment: @D.Winning and what's supposed to happen. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Which functions should get called?

Comment: I have added the player object at the bottom of my question for your reference. healSelf(20); should be called when clicking on weak potion and healSelf(45); should be called when brewers potion is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start at the beginning here. This line

```
var weakPotion 
     = new invItem('Weak Potion', 'Consumable', 'A weak health potion.', 10, healSelf(20));
```

Already does not do what you think it does! It will *immediately* execute the function - which is not what you're trying to do. Instead you should be storing a *reference to the function to execute*. Fix it by returning a new function to be called later

```
function healSelf(amt) {
  return function(){
    if (player.currentHealth < player.maxHealth) {
      player.currentHealth += amt;
      if (player.currentHealth >= player.maxHealth) {
        player.currentHealth = player.maxHealth;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, when you pass a reference to a function, to later execute that function use parentheses:

```
onclick="items[i].effect()"
```

But this still wont work - `items[i]` only exists in the loop - not when the page is running. One way to solve this is to not attach an `onclick` directly (especially when using jQuery) and instead attach a click handler to those links using `index()` to find the right `item`

```
function showItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    playerUi.innerHTML += '<div class="item-container"><a href="#" class="item-name">' + items[i].name + '</a><br /><p class="desc-p">' + items[i].description + '<br />Value: ' + items[i].price + '</p></div>';
  }
}
```

and elsewhere

```
$(document).on('click','.item-name',function(){
   var index = $(this).index();
   items[index].effect();
});
```

Comment: that cleared up stuff I wasn't sure about myself. Very new to JS :)

Comment: Thanks for this Jamie, it worked in a way - I have also added items.splice(index, 1); - it only seems to apply the effect (and remove the item) of the first item in the list however, any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Please see the demo link again for clarification as to what I mean - press the test button a few times to gain some levels and apply points to endurance to have some missing health to work with.

Comment: Basically, index always equals 0?

Comment: @D.Winning you might need `var index = $(this).parent().index();` - I hadnt noticed the `a` was inside a container

Answer (score 1):

Items should have unique IDs so you can easily access them, remove from item list etc. So, ended up with something like that.

```js
let playerUi = $('#inv');

let player = {
  currentHealth: 100,
  maxHealth: 100
};

let items = [];

function showItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    let item = '<li data-itemid="' + items[i].id + '">' + items[i].name + '<br>Description: ' + items[i].description + '</li>';

    playerUi.append(item);

  }
}

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Change 5 to higher number for more unique IDs
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

function invItem(name, type, desc, price, eff) {
  this.id = makeid();
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.description = desc;
  this.price = price;
  this.effect = eff;
};

function healSelf(amt) {
  return function() {
    console.log("Before heal:" + player.currentHealth);
    player.currentHealth = Math.min(player.currentHealth+amt, player.maxHealth);
    console.log("After heal:" + player.currentHealth);
  }
}

items[0] = new invItem('Weak Potion', 'Consumable', 'A weak health potion.', 10, healSelf(20));
items[1] = new invItem('Brewers Potion', 'Consumable', 'A standard health potion.', 23, healSelf(45));
items[2] = new invItem('Strongest Potion', 'Consumable', 'This potion is too strong.', 100, healSelf(80));

showItems();

$('li').on('click', function(e) {

  let id = e.target.dataset.itemid;
  let item = $.grep(items, function(e) {return e.id == id;})[0];
  console.log("Using: " + item.name);
  player.currentHealth -= 40;
  item.effect();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="inv">

</ul>
```